# PHP Array Merge форматирует ключ

Tags: php

Есть массивы:

```
$a = array('one' => '');
$b = array('404' => 'true');
```

Я делаю:

```
print_r(array_merge($a, $b));
```

Вопрос, почему получается следующе, и как сделать чтобы вместо 0, было 404?

```
(
    [one] => 
    [0] => true
)
```

Comment: `var_dump($a + $b);`

Comment: @Эдуард дело в том, что мне нужно передать эти два объеденных массива в качестве аргумента функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте оператор `+`, сохраняйте результат в переменную, и передавайте эту переменную дальше:

```
$a = array('one' => '');
$b = array('404' => 'true');
$c = $a + $b;

print_r($c);
```

**UPD**: Если вариант со сложением массивов не безопасен, можно построить промежуточный массив, и обработать его вложенными циклами:

```
$a = ['one' => ''];
$b = ['404' => 'true'];
$tmp = [$a, $b];

foreach ($tmp as $arr)  {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $c[$k] = $v;
    }
}

var_dump($c);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  'one' => string '' (length=0)
  404 => string 'true' (length=4)
```

Comment: Я помечу ваше решение как корректное, но почему пхп себя так ведет, остается загадкой.

Answer (score 1):

потому что это документированное поведение функции [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php)

> Если входные массивы имеют одинаковые строковые ключи, тогда каждое последующее значение будет заменять предыдущее. Однако, если массивы имеют одинаковые числовые ключи, значение, упомянутое последним, не заменит исходное значение, а будет добавлено в конец массива.
>
> **В результирующем массиве значения исходного массива с числовыми ключами будут перенумерованы в возрастающем порядке, начиная с нуля.**

сложение же массивов даст [несколько иной результат](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.array.php).

> Оператор + возвращает левый массив, к которому был присоединен правый массив. **Для ключей, которые существуют в обоих массивах, будут использованы значения из левого массива, а соответствующие им элементы из правого массива будут проигнорированы.**

Comment: В результирующем массиве значения исходного массива с числовыми ключами будут перенумерованы в возрастающем порядке, начиная с нуля. - но ведь мой ключ это '404' в кавычках, то есть строка.

Comment: @Rymar пхп не строго типизированный язык. если  это можно представить числом, то это число.

Comment: до тех пор пока вы не используете тождественное равенство `===`

Comment: То есть к оператору + надо осторожно относиться, если массивы обычные, числовые: результат вероятно будет не тот, что ожидается.